# How to play HTML 5 videos in native player?

Tags: html, ipad, video, html5-video

I've a HTML5 webpage and I've included a video in it. I would like know, If a user try to play that video on the IPad can we open that in native player?

I even tried following blog post http://alisonfoxall.com/open-source-html5-code-for-embedding-ipad-video-player/ but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, We can play in iPad the video in native player we just need to include some meta tags for it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>

<video controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A little more explanation expected.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use Javascript. Pretty simple from there, though.

```
function playVideo () {
  var myVideo = document.querySelector('video')[0];
   myVideo.play();
  myVideo.webkitEnterFullscreen();
}
```

iPads naturally play videos inline ([see this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html)) so you just need to select the video using a querySelector and then use JS to play it.